# LINQ-to-objects, get value from dictionary

Tags: linq-to-objects

I have an on object, called user, that has a property of type dictionary called AttributeBag.

I want to pull out the Key in the AttributeBag of "PasswordQuestion" and get its value.

The below is not correct...

```
var x = user.Find(a => a.AttributeBag.Key["PasswordQuestion"]).value;
```

help

Answer (score 6):

```
var x = user.Find(a => a.AttributeBag.Key["PasswordQuestion"]).value;
```

becomes

```
var x = user.AttributeBag.Select(s => s.Key == "PasswordQuestion")
        .First().ToString();
```

or

```
var x = (from a in _user.AttributeBag
         where a.Key == "PasswordQuestion"
         select a.Value).First().ToString();
```

5000 ways to skin a cat

Answer (score 1):

`var x = user.AttributeBag.Where(a => a.Key == "PasswordQuestion")
                        .First().Value.ToString();`